# Is there a way to output an llvm jit module into file?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-c++-api

I'd like to save a llvm module into file `xxx.ll`
maybe the code just like

```cpp
llvm::module M;
...
ofstream << M;
```

Is there given function in llvm? or we need do some transformation for `M` then we can use `ofstream`
I'm using llvm 14

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`llvm::Module::print`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Module.html#a8ee5166cba8576e41617fc96aec1fb85) method. You'll also need to construct [`llvm::raw_os_ostream`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1raw__os__ostream.html).